# ELF sections not being mapped to segments as expected

Tags: compiler-construction, x86-64, elf

I am writing a compiler and am just starting to generate ELF executables from scratch. I am creating a `.text` section (although it doesn't have a name because I am not creating a string table yet), and trying to put it within a `PT_LOAD` segment. However, `readelf` isn't reporting that the section is mapped into the segment and `objdump` refuses to disassemble the code in the `.text` section. This is the readout of `readelf`, with some bits omitted for brevity:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x0
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          122 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         1
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         2
  Section header string table index: 0

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0] <no-name>         NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] <no-name>         PROGBITS         0000000008048000  00000078
       0000000000000002  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     16
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), l (large)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)

There are no section groups in this file.

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  LOAD           0x0000000000000078 0x0000000008048000 0x0000000008048000
                 0x0000000000000002 0x0000000000000002  R E    1000
```

At offset `0x78`, I am just emitting two `push ebx`s (opcode `0x53`) for testing. Here is the hex dump:

```
00000000  7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.ELF............|
00000010  02 00 3e 00 01 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..>.............|
00000020  40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  7a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |@.......z.......|
00000030  00 00 00 00 40 00 38 00  01 00 40 00 02 00 00 00  |....@.8...@.....|
00000040  01 00 00 00 05 00 00 00  78 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........x.......|
00000050  00 80 04 08 00 00 00 00  00 80 04 08 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000060  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000070  00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00  53 53 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........SS......|
00000080  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000000b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00  |................|
000000c0  00 00 06 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 80 04 08 00 00  |................|
000000d0  00 00 78 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00  |..x.............|
000000e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000000fa
```

Edit: Question - Why isn't a section to segment mapping shown between the two, and why is no disassembly shown by `objdump`?

Comment: Did you have a question? You state a bunch of facts, and then...? If your question is "why doesn't readelf show section to segment mapping, the answer is likely going to be: don't create a section with no name".

Comment: @EmployedRussian - added a question. So is a string table with section names required for disassembling with `objdump` and showing mappings? I'll try adding a string table when I get home, and see if it makes a difference, thanks!

Comment: @EmployedRussian yup - it seems like a string table is needed to report the mappings for some reason. If you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why isn't a section to segment mapping shown between the two

Because there are no *valid* sections (as far as `readelf` can tell).

> and why is no disassembly shown by objdump?

`objdump` also uses *sections*.

Even though sections are not required for the *executable* part of `ELF` lifetime, a lot of tools depend on sections being present. For example, the lone segment you have in your executable contains both code and the `ELF` header, and the program header. Generally you *don't* want to disassemble the header. Without sections, `objdump` doesn't know where to start disassembly from.

Comment: To elaborate, for a section to be valid it's 'name' field must point to a non-zero entry in a valid string table.